# Why do we need func.TimerRequest when I am not using it in my function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am using Azure Function to get data, process it and export it to a SQL database every 5 min.

I am trying to understand why do I need `func.TimerRequest` in my main function if I am not using it. But when I remove it, `func start` will fail.

Here's the simplified version of my code:

```
import azure.functions as func

def get_data():
    # import some data


def export_data():
    # export data to SQL database


def main(timer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    export_data()

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

As we can see, in my function argument I have `timer: func.TimerRequest`.

My `function.json` file:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "main.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "timer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `timer-triggered azure function` is executed, the settings in `function.json` will be converted into an object whose type is [TimerRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.timerrequest?view=azure-python). In short, with `func.TimerRequest`, the `timer-triggered azure function` can get the settings like schedule from config file, then it can be executed correctly.

Please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python#example) for more details.